# Does "scaler" multiply twice?

Tags: openmdao

I have always had some trouble  with the scaling options within openmdao. As sometimes the scaling works implicitly during the matrix solvers while some other times explicitly etc.  The problem I have now is the scaling of the constraint and recording it. I have used the [Cantilever beam example](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/examples/beam_optimization/beam_optimization.html)

I added the scaler=2

```
    self.add_constraint('volume_comp.volume', equals=volume,scaler=2)
```

I did not change volume = 0.01 constraint value. If i set scaler=1 the recorded output of  the constraint volume is equal to 0.01 at the end of the optimization. However if i set scaler=2 volume variable is 0.04. And for scaler=10, volume output is equal to 1 etc. Is there an extra multiplication.

The optimized value does not change no matter what, which I assume expected because this scaling is only for normalization (as far as I understand).

Below is one line changed sample code and the recorder, I am using OpenMDAO 2.5.0

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

from openmdao.api import Group, IndepVarComp

from openmdao.test_suite.test_examples.beam_optimization.components.moment_comp import MomentOfInertiaComp
from openmdao.test_suite.test_examples.beam_optimization.components.local_stiffness_matrix_comp import LocalStiffnessMatrixComp
from openmdao.test_suite.test_examples.beam_optimization.components.states_comp import StatesComp
from openmdao.test_suite.test_examples.beam_optimization.components.displacements_comp import DisplacementsComp
from openmdao.test_suite.test_examples.beam_optimization.components.compliance_comp import ComplianceComp
from openmdao.test_suite.test_examples.beam_optimization.components.volume_comp import VolumeComp


class BeamGroup(Group):

    def initialize(self):
        self.options.declare('E')
        self.options.declare('L')
        self.options.declare('b')
        self.options.declare('volume')
        self.options.declare('num_elements', int)

    def setup(self):
        E = self.options['E']
        L = self.options['L']
        b = self.options['b']
        volume = self.options['volume']
        num_elements = self.options['num_elements']
        num_nodes = num_elements + 1

        force_vector = np.zeros(2 * num_nodes)
        force_vector[-2] = -1.

        inputs_comp = IndepVarComp()
        inputs_comp.add_output('h', shape=num_elements)
        self.add_subsystem('inputs_comp', inputs_comp)

        I_comp = MomentOfInertiaComp(num_elements=num_elements, b=b)
        self.add_subsystem('I_comp', I_comp)

        comp = LocalStiffnessMatrixComp(num_elements=num_elements, E=E, L=L)
        self.add_subsystem('local_stiffness_matrix_comp', comp)

        comp = StatesComp(num_elements=num_elements, force_vector=force_vector)
        self.add_subsystem('states_comp', comp)

        comp = DisplacementsComp(num_elements=num_elements)
        self.add_subsystem('displacements_comp', comp)

        comp = ComplianceComp(num_elements=num_elements, force_vector=force_vector)
        self.add_subsystem('compliance_comp', comp)

        comp = VolumeComp(num_elements=num_elements, b=b, L=L)
        self.add_subsystem('volume_comp', comp)

        self.connect('inputs_comp.h', 'I_comp.h')
        self.connect('I_comp.I', 'local_stiffness_matrix_comp.I')
        self.connect(
            'local_stiffness_matrix_comp.K_local',
            'states_comp.K_local')
        self.connect(
            'states_comp.d',
            'displacements_comp.d')
        self.connect(
            'displacements_comp.displacements',
            'compliance_comp.displacements')
        self.connect(
            'inputs_comp.h',
            'volume_comp.h')

        self.add_design_var('inputs_comp.h', lower=1e-2, upper=10.)
        self.add_objective('compliance_comp.compliance')
        self.add_constraint('volume_comp.volume', equals=volume,scaler=10)

import numpy as np

from openmdao.api import Problem, ScipyOptimizeDriver,SqliteRecorder

E = 1.
L = 1.
b = 0.1
volume = 0.01

num_elements = 50

prob = Problem(model=BeamGroup(E=E, L=L, b=b, volume=volume, num_elements=num_elements))

prob.driver = ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-9
prob.driver.options['disp'] = True
recorder = SqliteRecorder('abc.sql')
prob.driver.add_recorder(recorder)
prob.driver.recording_options['includes'] = []
prob.driver.recording_options['record_inputs'] = True
#        prob.driver.recording_options['record_outputs'] = True
prob.driver.recording_options['record_objectives'] = True
prob.driver.recording_options['record_constraints'] = True
prob.driver.recording_options['record_desvars'] = True
prob.driver.recording_options['record_derivatives'] = True
prob.setup()

prob.run_driver()

print(prob['inputs_comp.h'])
prob.cleanup()


#%%
import re
from openmdao.api import  CaseReader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os,json as js    
import matplotlib

cr = CaseReader('abc.sql')
case_keys = cr.list_cases()
obj=[]
for i, case_key in enumerate(case_keys):
    case = cr.get_case(case_key)   
    derivs = cr.get_case(i).jacobian
#        for k in derivs:
#            print(k,derivs[k])

    recorded_objectives  = case.get_objectives()
    recorder_constraints = case.get_constraints()        
    recorder_desvars     = case.get_design_vars()        
    recorder_responses   = case.get_responses()        
    for k in recorder_desvars:
        print(k,recorder_desvars[k])
    for k in recorder_constraints:
        print(k,recorder_constraints[k])  
    for k in recorded_objectives:
        print(k,recorded_objectives[k])  
        obj.append(recorded_objectives[k])

    print('-----------')



#    
#print(obj)
#obj[2]=obj[1]
#print(len(obj))
plt.plot(obj,'*')
```

Comment: The following pull request solves the issue:
https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/pull/861

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables in the recorder are indeed scaled twice. In the driver the values are scaled properly. You can compare it for the last case with the code below. Scaling is done in `_apply_voi_meta()` in the `Case` class.

```
#%%

cr = CaseReader('abc.sql')
case_keys = cr.list_cases()
obj=[]
for i, case_key in enumerate(case_keys):
    case = cr.get_case(case_key)
    derivs = cr.get_case(i).jacobian
#        for k in derivs:
#            print(k,derivs[k])

    recorded_objectives  = case.get_objectives()
    recorder_constraints = case.get_constraints()
    recorder_desvars     = case.get_design_vars()
    recorder_responses   = case.get_responses()
    for k in recorder_desvars:
        print(k,recorder_desvars[k])
    for k in recorder_constraints:
        print(k,recorder_constraints[k])
    for k in recorded_objectives:
        print(k,recorded_objectives[k])
        obj.append(recorded_objectives[k])

    print('-----------')

print('\nDRIVER:\n\n')

for k, v in iteritems(driver.get_design_var_values()):
    print(k, v)
for k, v in iteritems(driver.get_constraint_values()):
    print(k, v)
for k, v in iteritems(driver.get_objective_values()):
    print(k, v)
```

Now it is clear, that the source of the problem is the recorder. In your case you call *both* the `get_constraints()` and the `get_responses()` methods on the case. In these methods mutable variables are scaled. So when you return the value, the variable `vals` in `_apply_voi_meta()` also gets scaled. As many times you call any function, that is scaling the same variables, the variables will be scaled at each function call as a side effect.

See the example below:

```
#%%

cr = CaseReader('abc.sql')
case_keys = cr.list_cases()
obj=[]

scaled = True

for i, case_key in enumerate(case_keys):
    case = cr.get_case(case_key)
    derivs = cr.get_case(i).jacobian
#        for k in derivs:
#            print(k,derivs[k])

    recorded_objectives  = case.get_objectives(scaled=scaled)
    recorder_constraints = case.get_constraints(scaled=scaled)
    recorder_desvars     = case.get_design_vars()
    # recorder_responses   = case.get_responses(scaled=scaled)

    case.get_constraints(scaled=scaled)
    case.get_constraints(scaled=scaled)

    for k in recorder_desvars:
        print(k,recorder_desvars[k])
    for k in recorder_constraints:
        print(k,recorder_constraints[k])
    for k in recorded_objectives:
        print(k,recorded_objectives[k])
        obj.append(recorded_objectives[k])

    print('-----------')

print('\nDRIVER:\n\n')

for k, v in iteritems(driver.get_design_var_values()):
    print(k, v)
for k, v in iteritems(driver.get_constraint_values()):
    print(k, v)
for k, v in iteritems(driver.get_objective_values()):
    print(k, v)
```

If the scaler is 10, the constraint will be 1000 (or 10^3) times the unscaled value, because now I called the `get_constraints()` method 3 times.